# Using lambda expressions in array.convertall()

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm still getting acquainted with delegates and lambdas, I'm not using LINQ, and I also only discovered the `ConvertAll` function today, so I'm experimenting and asking this to bolster my understanding.

The task I had was to establish whether a string of numbers were even or odd. So first, convert the string list to an int list, and from there into a bool list. As bloated as the code would be, I wondered if I could get it all on one line and reduce the need for an extra for loop.

```
string numbers = "2 4 7 8 10";

List<bool> evenBools = new List<bool>(Array.ConvertAll(numbers.Split(' '), (x = Convert.Int32) => x % 2 == 0))
```

The expected result is [true, true, false, true, true]. Obviously the code doesn't work.

I understand that the second argument of `Array.ConvertAll`) requires the conversation to take place. From string to int, that's simply `Convert.ToInt32`. Is it possible to do that on the fly though (i.e. on the left side of the lambda expression), so that I can get on with the bool conversion and return on the right?

Comment: " (ie. on the left side of the lambda expression)" - the left hand side of `=>` is only *ever* a list of parameters, possibly in parentheses, possibly using implicit typing. It's not clear what you expected `x = Convert.Int32` to mean there, but you should reset your expectations of what can appear to the left hand side of `=>`.

Comment: After Linq has come, there is no _need_ to use `Array.ConvertAll<>` in you case (but it is possible). You could do `var evenBools = numbers.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x) % 2 == 0).ToList();`

Answer (score 4):

Second parameter of [`ConvertAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=netcore-3.1) method is [`Converter<TInput,TOutput>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.converter-2?view=netcore-3.1) delegate. You can use anonymous method here, pass string `input` to it (left side of `=>`), parse to `int` inside and return `bool` value, indicating whether it's even or odd

```cs
var boolArray = Array.ConvertAll(numbers.Split(' '), input => Convert.ToInt32(input) % 2 == 0);
List<bool> evenBools = new List<bool>(boolArray);
```

Finally create a `List<bool>` from array.

Left side of [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) contains input parameters only (`input` string in your case). Right side is used for expressions and statements, here you have a logic for parsing and return a `bool` value.

With help of `System.Linq` it can be written on the similar way

```cs
var boolArray = numbers.Split(' ').Select(input => Convert.ToInt32(input) % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```

You also might use `int.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: @TomPengelly Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolList = numbers.Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList().ConvertAll(i => i % 2 == 0);
```